Why is my status code 403 when trying to Scrape from GlassDoor?
I am trying to scrape job info from glass door. Similar code structure worked fine for LinkedIn, but I'm having issue here. I'm getting a Status Code of 403 so I'm guessing I'm running into some sort of wall on the GlassDoor back end. I was wondering if anyone could help me figure out why.
    #Define URL
    url = "https://www.glassdoor.com/Job/united-states-it-entry-level-jobs-    SRCH_IL.0,13_IN1_KO14,28.html"
    
    #Retrieve HTML Content
    response = requests.get(url)
    html = response.content
    
    #Parae HTML
    soup = BeautifulSoup(html, 'html.parser')
    
    #Pull Job Titles
    jobListing = soup.find_all('div', {'class': 'jobCard JobCard_jobCardContent__X81Ew'})
    for div in jobListing:
        #Using this to test if it finds the div
        print("Found Div")
    else:
        print("Didn't find Div")
    #    for a in div.find_all('a', {'class': 'JobCard_jobTitle___7I6y'}):
    #        print(a.text.strip())
    
    if response.status_code == 200:
        print("Yes")
    else:
        print(response.status_code)

I was expecting to be able to find that Div and pull the data, but that is not the case

They are checking for and rejecting scrapers to protect their copyrighted content.  It doesn't work from wget either.  You may be able to play with the browser ID.

Probably worth noting that if they’re blocking scrapers intentionally they might have something in their ToS that you’d be breaking by circumventing that (even if they weren’t it could still violate their ToS).

Try to set User-Agent header when making a request to the server:
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

headers = {
    "User-Agent": "Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Ubuntu; Linux x86_64; rv:124.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/124.0"
}

url = "https://www.glassdoor.com/Job/united-states-it-entry-level-jobs-SRCH_IL.0,13_IN1_KO14,28.html"

response = requests.get(url, headers=headers)
soup = BeautifulSoup(response.content, "html.parser")

for a in soup.select('a[id^="job-title"]'):
    print(a.text)

Prints:
After Hours NOC Analyst - Entry Level IT
IT Security Governance Analyst Level I
IT Audit Temp (Entry Level - 3 month temp paid position)
Restaurant IT Analyst Level I
Junior ServiceNow HRSD Developer
IT Analyst I
Junior IT Operations Engineer
Network Engineers, Entry Level
Entry-Level Unix Systems Administrator
IT Support Specialist
IT Engineer(Entry-Mid Level)
Urgent IT Telecaller Executive
Product Manager - Entry Level
IT Support Generalist
IT Analyst I
Junior IT Administrator
UWB Systems Engineer - Entry Level
Entry level IT Specialist
Entry Level IT Support Technician
Helpdesk Engineer (Entry-Level)
IT Project Coordinator Intern
Entry-Level Cyber Security Analyst
Onsite - Remote IT Support
Level 1 IT Help Desk Analyst -GA
Electronic Systems Engineer (Entry-Level)
IT Support Level 1
Systems Analyst
IT Help Desk Technician
IT Field Tech I
Entry-Level ERP Analyst


Could you explain why this works?

@Gannan307 Some servers are configured when then see non-browser user agent, they block it (but it depends from server to server, it's not something universal)
